# Boost.Regex: regex_replace - pass the format function as a lambda expression

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, c++11, lambda

what I want to achieve is to pass a lambda expression to a function that uses that passed expression as a formatter function for the `boost::xpressive::regex_replace` function. The code should work in VC++ using VS 2010.

If I had a function

```
void test1(){
    std::string str("foo");
    sregex re(icase("foo"));
    str = regex_replace(str,re,[](const smatch &match){ return "bar";});
}
```

I can easily pass a lambda expression as a format function. It can be passed as a function pointer as well:

```
std::string test2_format(const smatch &match){
    return "bar2";
}

void test2_replace(std::string(*fun)(const smatch &match)){
    std::string str("foo");
    sregex re(icase("foo"));
    str = regex_replace(str,re,fun);
}

void test2(){
    test2_replace(test2_format);
}
```

But how can I pass a lambda expression to a function? If I called something like

```
test2_replace([](const smatch &match)->std::string{return "bar3";});
```

I get the error

> error C2664: 'test2_replace' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   '`anonymous-namespace'::' to 'std::string (__cdecl *)(const
>   boost::xpressive::smatch &)'

This error occurs on VS 2013 as well.

[Edit] According to [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572138) lambda to function pointer conversion should be supported / fixed. [/Edit]

Do you have any idea what I might try?

Comment: Visual C++ doesn't have the lambda-to-function-pointer conversion implemented yet. Just use a template: `template<class F> vodi test2_replace(F f)`

Comment: @Xeo I added a link in my question that says they should support it. However, can you give me an example of your proposal?

Comment: @muffel I guess what Xeo meant was something like `template<class F> void test2_replace(F fun) { std::string str("foo"); sregex re(icase("foo")); str = regex_replace(str,re,fun); }`